# Create and synchronize development, staging and production servers?

Tags: linux, lamp, vagrant, linode

I'm building a PHP application, and I'm running all the development environment (Netbeans IDE, Apache, PHP and PostgreSQL) inside the same virtual machine.

I would like to prepare three diferents server:
- A development server
- A testing/staging server, to test the application with real data, but before going live
- The production server, the one that users will use

I think that the best (and cheaper) solution will be creating two virtual machines (one for the dev server and another for the testing server), and a Linode VPS for the production server.

Is this correct? I'm in the correct way?

And my main problem: how can I synchronize the servers creation and update? Maybe using Vagrant on my local machine (I've never used it)? But how can I tell Vagrant and Linode which packages I want to be installed on each machine?

Of course, the database in the staging server will be imported manually (or with some script when running tests, but it won't be synchronized with the development server).

**EDIT**

I've reworded the question: ***Which tool can I use to create and maintain the three servers with the same OS (Ubuntu 14.04, in this case) and packages, and to install new packages to all the servers at the same time?*** Remeber that one of the servers is an VPS at Linode, and the others are local virtual machines.

Comment: A bit broad this question is. I recommend reading something like http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0321601912/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1435819132&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SY200_QL40&keywords=continuous+delivery&dpPl=1&dpID=51NbiDn81NL&ref=plSrch and asking very specific questions here.

Comment: We use a combination of Puppet and Git to do what you want to do, but that might be a bit overkill for you..